# Qual é a diferença entre projeto ("project") e aplicação ("app") no Django?

Tags: python, django

Eu tinha feito alguns testes como framework Django há um tempo atrás, e só agora que voltei a testá-lo novamente, reparei que existem dois comandos, que acabaram me confundindo:

```
django-admin startproject nome_do_projeto
```

E também temos:

```
django-admin startapp nome_do_app
```

Eu não me lembro de ter precisado usar o comando `django-admin startapp` das últimas vezes que o utilizei. Isso se trata de alguma opção nova?

Tenho algumas pergunta a fazer:

- Qual é a diferença entre um e outro?
- Para o Django, o que é um "projeto" e o que é uma "aplicação"?
- Existem diferenças de estrutura?

Comment: Tenho a pequena impressão que alguma coisa mudal, pois eu não lembro da época que eu mexia no Django de ter o script `apps.py` dentro  da pasta do projeto...

Answer (score 4):

Primeiro, vamos analisar a estrutura de diretórios que é gerada quando criamos um projeto:

```
mysite/
    manage.py
    mysite/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
```

> Projeto criado com o comando `django-admin startproject mysite`, a título de informação.

- O diretório pai `mysite` é onde tudo será organizado. O projeto e os aplicativos serão organizados neste diretório. No início, é comum o desenvolvedor acreditar que este é o projeto Django criado, mas não, é apenas um diretório para separar tudo do resto dos arquivos na máquina. Tanto que o nome deste diretório não é importante - só leva o mesmo nome do projeto por padrão.
- O diretório `mysite` interno, por sua vez, é o projeto Django criado. Visto que a definição no [glossário](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/glossary/#term-project) consta que o **projeto** é um pacote Python (um diretório de códigos) que contém todas as configurações da instância do Django em questão. Pode ainda conter configurações de banco de dados, configurações gerais da aplicação, entre outros.

O projeto por si só não faz muita coisa, pois, na filosofia do Django, um projeto deve ser composto de aplicativos (*app*).

Os **aplicativos** (*app*), por sua vez, podem ser definidos como um conjunto de funcionalidades interrelacionadas que são definidas para criar ou manter um aspecto do projeto. Em geral, as apps são definidas para serem o mais reutilizáveis possível, sendo encarregadas de apenas uma função bastante especifica. Também considera-se que as apps serão, ao máximo, independentes entre si - sendo dependentes apenas quando realmente faz sentido.

Por exemplo, se sua aplicação (projeto) necessitará de uma área de Blog, você criará uma app para isso, mas para APENAS isso. Nesta app você definirá todas as estruturas de tabelas do banco de dados necessárias e todas as regras de negócio para que um blog seja funcional.

*Mas eu quero criar um sistema de gerenciamento de acesso para usuários no meu blog*, ok, mas faça isso em outra app. Não tem um sistema de gerenciamento de usuários? Outra app. Em outras palavras (que são quase as mesmas), as apps são responsáveis poder denifir os aspectos da aplicação/projeto e poderão ser reutilizadas em quantos projetos forem necessárias.

Resumidamente, o projeto é responsável por configurar a instância do Django em questão conforme as necessidades da aplicação e possui um conjunto de apps que definem os aspectos da mesma.

> Lembre-se que o Django é um pacote Python instalado no servidor, então é o mesmo código sendo executado pelos diversos sites que podem estar hospedados no mesmo, por isso diz-se sobre a *instância* do Django.

---

Ressalto, aqui, que ao meu ver a melhor tradução para o termo *app* é aplicativo e não aplicação, pois este é normalmente utilizado para referir-se ao conjunto como um todo, enquanto aplicativo expressa uma ideia menos generalista.

Answer (score 1):

Você  pode ter vários aplicativos dentro de um projeto. Cada App pode cuidar de uma parte diferente do projeto. Por exemplo, existe um App chamado admin que já é instalado por defult no projeto que serve , dentre outras coisas, para gerenciar as contas de usuário,  Esse App e fornecido pelo próprio django, Aí você pode criar os seus com suas finalidades de forma a atender as necessidades do projeto